# How to get cumulative total of multiple column by awk?

Tags: awk

I have a pipe delimited file like:

```
KALPESH|100|200|300
KALPESH|200|300|400
KALPESH|300|400|500
KALPESH|400|500|600
```

I am using:

```
awk -F"|" '{ name[$1]+=$2 } END { for (c in name) print c"|"name[c] }' earning1
```

Which gives result for column 2 only like:

```
KALPESH|1000
```

I have to do this for each column then I use `join` command 
But I want cumulative total of all 3 column like:

```
KALPESH|1000|1400|1800
```

Is this possible by single awk?

Comment: Please provide a better minimal example. Minimal does not mean the shortest possible piece of input, but rather a short piece of input that represents the scenario. You mention in a comment to an answer below that it does not work because the first field is not always `KALPESH`, so please do provide the sample with non-`KALPESH` first fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with @plumo and `datamash` as a rule but sticking with OP request for `awk` and assuming that `KALPESH` has a friend `RAJESH` so the input file is

```
KALPESH|100|200|300
KALPESH|200|300|400
RAJESH|300|400|500
RAJESH|400|500|599
KALPESH|300|400|500
KALPESH|400|500|600
RAJESH|100|200|300
RAJESH|200|300|400
```

Then

```
awk -F\| '{
    flds=(NF>flds)?NF:flds; 
    nm[$1]=$1;
    for (f=2; f<=NF; f++) sum[$1"|"f]+=$f
  }END{
    for (n in nm) {printf "%s", n;
      for (f=2; f<=flds; f++) printf "%s", FS sum[n"|"f]; print""
  }
}' file

KALPESH|1000|1400|1800
RAJESH|1000|1400|1799
```

If `KALPESH` is alone and the number of fields is constant then this collapses to

```
awk -F\| '{
    for (f=2; f<=4; f++) sum[f]+=$f
  }END{
    printf "%s", "KALPESH";
      for (f=2; f<=4; f++) printf "%s", FS sum[f]; print""
  }' file
```

Or even to

```
awk -F\| '{s2+=$2; s3+=$3; s4+=$4}END{print "KALPESH" FS s2 FS s3 FS s4}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

For tasks like this I prefer more specialized tools like `datamash`

```
$ datamash -t '|' -g 1 sum 2 sum 3 sum 4 < file
KALPESH|1000|1400|1800
```

or `csvsql` tool from [`csvkit`](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
$ csvsql -H -d'|' --query '
    select a,sum(b),sum(c),sum(d) from file group by a' file | csvformat -D'|'

a|sum(b)|sum(c)|sum(d)
KALPESH|1000|1400|1800
```

Answer (score -1):

I would think so. Without knowing awk very well, the trick you do in the body by keeping track of the total  of column two, using variable *name* can be expanded to do totals of all columns. To give an idea: try this and then adapt it to your needs

```
awk -F"|" '{ total1 += $2; total2 += $3} END { print (total1, total2); }' earnings
```

It is not clear what exactly you want: is the contents of colomn 1 important? Should there be a total for all occurences, or is it always the same? The solution depends on this kind of things.
When you get stuck, let us know.

Comment: This is sample data. Where in example there is KALPESH, it could be any other name. So this one will not work for me. After this one i have to work with join command again.

Comment: can't you just combine this and yours: `total1[$1]` or do you have indefinite number of columns? If so, you should add that information to your question.

Comment: Thanks bu5hman. As you stated there may be more name. So this one works for me right way.